# MySQL Duplicate Entry for non Unique column update in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

In WordPress, I want to update the quantity by +1 if the record already exists in the cart by (query in the code).

Three columns are unique in the table. While updating `qty` column it is giving Duplicate Entry error in this code. However, If I use the direct query from console it is updating `qty` value without error.

Also this method I am calling in AjAX. That is returning undefined (probably in ajax error).

So how can I get this code work with Ajax, if no record than insert else just update the `qty` value by `+1`

> `$this->gs_db` is the database class instance and `$this->gs_db->db` is `$wpdb`

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_gs_pg_cart (
id            BIGINT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
product_group BIGINT(20)                       NOT NULL,
qty           INT(11)                          NOT NULL,
group_id      BIGINT(20)                       NOT NULL,
group_admin   BIGINT(20)                       NOT NULL,
group_user    BIGINT(20)                       NOT NULL,
added_at      DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX pg_cart_index (ID, product_group, group_id, group_admin, group_user),
UNIQUE pg_cart_unique (product_group, group_id, group_user)
);
```

## Class Method

```
/**
 * Add product group into the cart
 *
 * @param int      $group_id      group id
 * @param int      $product_group product group id
 * @param int|bool $group_user    group user / logged in id
 *
 * @return int inserted row id if new else update row id
 */
public function add_pg_to_cart($group_id, $product_group, $group_user = FALSE)
{

    $this->group_id      = $group_id;
    $this->qty           = 1;
    $this->product_group = $product_group;
    $this->group_admin   = $this->group_id;
    $this->group_user    = ($group_user) ? absint($group_user) : absint(get_current_user_id());

    // check if record is already exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_gs_pg_cart WHERE product_group = '%d' AND group_id = '%d' AND group_user = '%d'";

    $prepare = $this->gs_db->db->prepare($query, $this->product_group, $this->group_id, $this->group_user);
    $result  = $this->gs_db->db->get_row($prepare);

    if ($this->gs_db->db->num_rows > 0) {
        $this->qty += $result->qty;

        $this->gs_db->db->update($this->gs_db->get_pg_cart_table(), ['qty' => $this->qty], ['id' => $result->id], '%d');

        $this->id = $result->id;
    } else {

        // setup data to insert
        $this->data = [
            'product_group' => $this->product_group,
            'qty'           => $this->qty,
            'group_id'      => $this->group_id,
            'group_admin'   => $this->group_admin,
            'group_user'    => $this->group_user,
        ];

        // setup data format
        $this->format = [
            '%d',
            '%d',
            '%d',
            '%d',
            '%d',
        ];

        // insert record
        $this->gs_db->db->insert($this->gs_db->get_pg_cart_table(), $this->data, $this->format);

        // get the id for inserted record
        $this->id = $this->gs_db->db->insert_id;

    }

    return $this->id;

}
```

## Ajax Callback Function

```
function gs_pg_add_to_cart_ajax()
{

    // Check if user is logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
        // throw error if user is not logged in
        wp_send_json_error(__('Please login to order', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    // check and validate nonce
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));
    }

    $group_id      = 0;
    $product_group = 0;
    $cart_id       = 0;

    // validate product_group
    if ( ! isset($_POST[ 'product_group' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'product_group' ]) || $_POST[ 'product_group' ] <= 0) {
        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Product Group is not defined', 'group-shop'));
    } else {
        $product_group = absint($_POST[ 'product_group' ]);
    }

    // validate product_group
    if ( ! isset($_POST[ 'group_id' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'group_id' ]) || $_POST[ 'group_id' ] <= 0) {
        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Group is not defined', 'group-shop'));
    } else {
        $group_id = absint($_POST[ 'group_id' ]);
    }

    // initialize cart object
    $cart = new Group_Shop_Cart();
    // insert record
    $cart_id = $cart->add_pg_to_cart($group_id, $product_group);

    // if record inserted
    if ($cart_id > 0) {

        // show success message once record inserted
        wp_send_json_success(__('Product is added to cart', 'group-shop'));

    } else {

        // throw error if fails to insert record
        wp_send_json_error(__('Something went wrong', 'group-shop'));

    }

    // stop further execution once all process done
    wp_die();

}
```

## Javascript

```
(function ($) {

    $(function () {

        let response_alert = $('#response');
        response_alert.hide();

        $('form.gsGpAddToCart').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let formData = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({

                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: ajax_vars.ajax_url,
                data: formData + "&action=gs_pg_add_to_cart&nonce=" + ajax_vars.nonce,
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log(response);

                    let response_alert = $('#response');

                    if (response.success === true) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('success', response.data));
                    }

                    if (response.success === false) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', response.data));
                    }

                },
                error: function (response) {

                    let error_message = (response.data === undefined) ? 'Something went wrong!' : response.data;
                    response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', error_message));
                    gs_alert_stats();
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        // control dynamically created error with JS - close/hide
        function gs_alert_stats() {
            let gs_alert = $('.gs-message');
            $('.gs-close').on('click', function () {
                alerts('Clicked');
                $(this).parent(gs_alert).fadeOut();
            });
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Javascript is returning this error response `Something went wrong!` which is in `error: function (response)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the whole logic by using MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax.

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.

You already have the proper `UNIQUE` constraint in place, so you would just need to adapt the code of your class method to use the following query at once:

```
INSERT INTO wp_gs_pg_cart(product_group, group_id, group_admin, group_user, qty)
VALUES(%d, %d, %d, %d, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = qty + 1
```

Comment: So here I don't have to check existing entry separately. Wow, that's great. I was completely unaware of this... Let me try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CodeLover: exactly, you don't need all that logic in the code since MySQL pretty much has built-in support for that use case...

Comment: This is working fine except one issue. It is giving wrong AJAx response. I mean it is returning `error: function(response)` code on insert/update.

Comment: @CodeLover: ok so there is probably and issue with your ajax code. You mentionned initially that you were not getting proper response in Ajax anyway. I am not the Ajax guy, this is beyond my skills scope...

Comment: I have also posted Javascript code. It was working fine if only I use the Insert query. But query with update won't work. In fact, it is updating the record correctly but the response is not correct.

Comment: I have selected your answer as a working answer. However, I am still struggling with an AJAX response.

Comment: Thanks @CodeLover. You might want to ask another question specifically for the ajax problem (using the relevant tags, like `ajax`, `javascript`, ...)